# Laravel passing 2 parameters for update method

Tags: laravel, laravel-form

I have an EDIT button

```
<td><a href="{{action('InventoryItemController@edit', [$inventoryitem['id'], $inventoryitem['inventory_id']])}}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
```

And when i press it, it should edit an item based on ID and then when i update it, it should update it based on ID which works, but when I want to redirect back to index page I have to pass argument for that index method. So i added that inventory_id parameter to be passed along ID parameter but it wont recognize my inventory_id parameter in mine form.

```
<form method="put" action="{{action('InventoryItemController@update', $id, $inventory_id)}}">
```

But i get this error

```
Undefined variable: inventory_id
```

my route is like this

```
Route::post('inventory-items/{id}/{inventory_id}', 'InventoryItemController@update');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is here:

```
<form method="put" action="{{action('InventoryItemController@update', $id, $inventory_id)}}">
```

The route should look like:

```
route('InventoryItemController@update', ['id' => $id, 'inventory_id' => $inventory_id ])
```

Good luck!

Comment: I found an easier way to do it, but thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found easier way to do it, I just used one of the parameters ($id) in controller to find second parameter. Thanks for answers.